# Redirect with htaccess unless search

Tags: .htaccess, search, redirect

I'm not sure if this is possible, but here's whats going on.

I currently have an .htaccess rule to redirect example.com to store.example.com

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://store.example.com/[L,R=301]
```

This works great, however my search queries no longer work. What I'd like to do is redirect example.com to store.example.com unless I'm searching.

A sample search would look like this:

```
http://example.com/?s=my+search+query+string
```

Thank you in advanced for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^!(s=(.*))$
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://store.example.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the complete implementation would look like for this RewriteCond. I tried a couple different things, but most resulted in an infinite redirect loop. Any ideas?